# AudioKit v5 how to use AmplitudeTap and NodeRecorder with the same input node

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer, audiokit

I am trying to record input from the microphone and use AmplitudeTap for the same input. I can't find any examples of how to do this correctly and I am getting the following exception when calling the start function.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio', reason: 'required condition is false: nullptr == Tap()'
```

When I use NodeRecorder/AmplitudeTap separately they work fine. The error happens when I try to use both NodeRecorder and AmplitudeTap and initialize them with the same engine.input node.
Here is my code:

```
func setup() {        
    if mixer == nil {
        mixer = Mixer()
    }
    
    guard let input = engine.input else {
        return false
    }
    
    if recorder == nil {
        do {
            recorder = try NodeRecorder(node: input)
        } catch let err {
            print("Error: \(err)")
        }
    }
    if silencer == nil {
        let silencer = Fader(input, gain: 0.0)
        self.silencer = silencer
    }
    if !mixer.hasInput(silencer) {
        mixer.addInput(silencer)
    }
    
    engine.output = mixer
            
    tracker = AmplitudeTap(input) { amplitude in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.update(amplitude)
        }
    }
}

func release() -> Bool {
    mixer.removeAllInputs()
    engine.output = nil
    tracker.dispose()
}

func start() {
    do {
        tracker.start()
        try engine.start()
        NodeRecorder.removeTempFiles()
        try recorder?.record() // <- here the exception occurs
    } catch let err {
        print(err)
    }
}

func stop() -> String {
    engine.stop()
    tracker.stop()
    recorder?.stop()
    
    if let file = recorder?.audioFile {
        print("playing recorded file")
        player.file = file
        player.play()
    }
 }
```